# geom_bar overlapping labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

for simplicity lets suppose we have a database like

```
# A    
1 1  
2 2   
3 2    
4 2
5 3
```

We have a categorical variable "A" with 3 possible values (1,2,3). And im tring this code:

```
ggplot(df aes(x="", y=df$A, fill=A))+
   geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
```

The problem is that the labels are overlapping. Also i want to change the labes for 1,2,3 to x,y,z.
Here is picture of what is happening [image]

And here is a link for the actual data that im using.
https://a.uguu.se/anKhhyEv5b7W_Data.csv

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for ? because your column A has 13 different possible values and you ask for renaming labels of 1,2,3. What do you mean by overlapping labels ? Is it in the legend ?

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes`. You're also missing a comma

Comment: @camille tried that but still the axis are overlapped.

Comment: @dc37 sorry my mistake. The axis numbers are overlapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph does not correspond to the sample of data you are showing, so it is hard to be sure that the structure of your real data is actually the same.

Using a random example, I get the following plot:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:3,20, replace = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x="A", y=A, fill=as.factor(A)))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")  +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("x","y","z"))
```

[image]

**EDIT: Using data provided by the OP**

Here using your data, you should get the following plot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = "A",y = A, fill = as.factor(A)))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Or if you want the count of each individual values of A, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% group_by(A) %>% count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "A", y = n, fill = as.factor(A)))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi, i tried the code, but labels are still overlaping. Here is the actual data that i used https://a.uguu.se/anKhhyEv5b7W_Data.csv

Comment: I edited my answer using your data example, does it answer your question ?